# codeigniter complex join only if rows don't exist

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm making a dating application, much like tindler. Users can like or dislike other users, and if two users both like each other they get the option to chat with eachother. Currently building the query to pull a random profile and one of their pictures at random:

```
$data = $this->db
->select('users.id,display_name,city,state,gender,users_pictures.picture')
  ->join('users_pictures','users_pictures.user_id = users.id')
  ->order_by('id','RANDOM')
  ->limit(1)
  ->where(array('users.approved'=>1,'users_pictures.approved'=>1))
  ->where(array('users.id !='=>$user_id))->get('users')->result_array();
```

Now here's where I'm confused.. I have a table for likes_dislikes that consists of user_id, foreign_user_id, and event_type (like, dislike).

If you disliked or liked a user already, I do not want them in my results. The only means I can think of handling this is to perform a second query which checks this, and then does another 'random' query if you have already liked/disliked them so that you only see users you haven't already rated. Is there a better way?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of the `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` `MySQL` commands? The latter is the one you should try.

```
SELECT
 u.id, display_name, city, state, gender, up.picture
FROM
 users AS u
INNER JOIN
 users_pictures AS up ON up.user_id = u.id
WHERE
 NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 
     1 
    FROM
     likes_dislikes
    WHERE
     ld.foreign_user_id = u.id AND ld.user_id = $loggedInUserId
 )
```

The above will list all users, excluding all liked/disliked users. Trying to form this `SQL` statement with `Codeigniter` without the value being binded is a little hacky.

A brief investigation via Google (which may now be outdated) suggests that the following should be suitable.

```
//...rest of query
$db->where("
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM likes_dislikes 
    WHERE ld.foreign_user_id = u.id AND ld.user_id = $loggedInUserId
  ) AND 1 = ", 1);
```

Take notice to the last part `AND 1 = ", 1);`.

Comment: this was very close to working for me, but your answer inspired me to move in the right direction. I was able to find that the following worked flawlessly:

->where('NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users_likes_dislikes ld WHERE ld.foreign_user_id = users.id AND ld.user_id='.$this->user_id.')', '', FALSE)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I have little suggestion.

You can change like/dislike to numbers, -1 (dislike), 0 or NULL (unrated), 1 (like) for example.

It should simplify/shorten your queries.

After this - you can create view/query (or even better - SQL function) that will compute sum of ratings of 2 users, and sum like this may be used for many tasks if you think about it.

Comment: that's a great idea for computing things like popularity so that users can see data on how their profile is doing or etc, but ya that won't solve the issue with ensuring users don't see people they've already voted on. upvote because i like your idea though.

Comment: I think it may help with that filtering too. To filter profiles they've already voted you can just compare that number with 0. This will help you in getting rid of some "IS NULL" statements in application.

Comment: And one more thing - try to use database views and SQL stored procedures as much as you can. Writing complicated queries in CI is not comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a left outer join you will get the records in the left table that DO NOT have a match in the right table. (As outlined here http://www.khankennels.com/blog/index.php/archives/2007/04/20/getting-joins/)

You can specify this join type via the third parameter of CodeIgniter's active record join() function.

Thus, try using something like:

```php
$data = $this->db
             ->select('users.id,display_name,city,state,gender,users_pictures.picture')
             ->join('users_pictures','users_pictures.user_id = users.id')
             ->join('likes_dislikes', 'likes_dislikes.user_id = users.id', 'left outer')
             ->order_by('id','RANDOM')
             ->limit(1)
             ->where(array('users.approved'=>1,'users_pictures.approved'=>1))
             ->where(array('users.id !='=>$user_id))->get('users')->result_array();
```

Comment: it seemed like a reasonable idea but it still returned rows which had an existing like, ended up using the not exists function and that worked great. thank you much for your help though :)