# How to select with except code in Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

this is what I want in SQL: select id from mytable **except** select id from another_table,

but with CI's database library to use **EXCEPT** function,
how do I obtain it?

Comment: where('t1.id NOT IN (select otherid from table2)',NULL,FALSE)

Comment: `$this->db->where('jobs.job_id NOT IN (select tbl_job_applicants.job_id from tbl_job_applicants where tbl_job_applicants.employee_id='.$emp_id.')');`

I solved it like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using <kbd>[**`NOT EXISTS`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)</kbd>

```
SELECT
    MT.id
FROM
    mytable AS MT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        AT.id
    FROM another_table AS AT 
    WHERE AT.id = MT.id
)
```

Comment: thankyou for that, now I want it by using CodeIgniter's Database Class.
like using $this->db->select('MT.id')->from() etc. ...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the syntax of `CI`. Just tried to help with the raw query

Comment: This [**POST**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680676/codeigniter-complex-join-only-if-rows-dont-exist) might help you to convert it to `CI's` syntax

Comment: I had to do like this:.

  `$this->db->where('jobs.job_id NOT IN (select tbl_job_applicants.job_id from tbl_job_applicants where tbl_job_applicants.employee_id='.$emp_id.')');`

well.. at least it works :D